# Parse several queries in one

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've been struggling lately with some queries I need in parse that cannot be done in one using pointers or relation, so I was wondering if there would be a way to have several queries answer by calling parse only once ? Smth like that :

```
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class1"];
[query whereKey:@"key" equalTo:@"value"];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class2"];
    [query whereKey:@"key" equalTo:@"value"];

NSArray *myQueries = @[query1, query2];
[myQueries find objectsInBackground];
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364797/how-to-query-or-with-includekey-in-parse

You'd probably be interested in those answers.